# PayPal API Integration

Tags: api, paypal

Is it possible to use in production, in the same application, side by side:

1. PayPal Express Checkout API (for Digital Goods)
2. Adaptive Payments for everything else (preapproved payments, payments from merchant to other participants), i.e. payments that do not require user interaction with the PayPal web site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You can use any API's you want along side each other.